# Need to Deactivate Users with Python and Selenium in a Database on Front-end but Stale Reference

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

So I have been tasked with removing security groups from multiple users that are inactive in out database on the front-end. I am prohibited from backend management. So I am automating it via Selenium and Python. I was curious about the following stacktrace that I am getting from my procedure:

```py
  File ".\remove_sec_groups_inactive_users.py", line 127, in <module>
    element.send_keys(config['sec_group_removal']['target_user']['name_key']);
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

The issue is surrounding the code somewhere around this part.

```py
# Load users.json File
with open('users.json','r') as f:
          config = json.load(f)

# Send Keys to Lookup
# XPATH = //*[@id='brSecuredUsersLookupInput']
target_user = browser.find_element_by_id("brSecuredUsersLookupInput")
element.send_keys(config['sec_group_removal']['target_user']['name_key']);
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);
```

I would like to be able to make more users with a JSON file for payload, but for some odd reason it doesn't like that. I have thought about using

```
(config['sec_group_removal']['target_users']['user']['name_key'])
```

from a file that looks like this:

```
{
        "sec_group_removal": {
                "target_user": {
                         "user": {
                                "user_name": "firstname.lastname",
                                "name_key": "ABDLFNSDFKNE0033"
                          }
                }
        }
}
```

Alas this too is not working either so I am using the following:

```
{
        "sec_group_removal": {
                "target_user": {
                                "user_name": "NNNNNNN",
                                "name_key": "######"
                }
        }
}
```

Either way it is not sending the keys that I need to the loop component to search for the user:

[image]

I need help with sending a string into that look up, below is the web element:

```
<input class="lookupInput" type="text" name="brSecuredUsersLookupInput" id="brSecuredUsersLookupInput" title="Last First, Name Key, SSN, Name ID, Login" style="width: 100px;" tabindex="1" onkeydown="return lookupKeyPressed(event,&quot;&quot;,&quot;ssusrbrws001.w&quot;)" origvalue="" det="true" aria-labelledby="" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arose with how I was invoking the overall variable there that I was trying to pass off the send_keys method.

```py
target_user = browser.find_element_by_id("brSecuredUsersLookupInput")
element.send_keys(config['sec_group_removal']['target_user']['name_key']);
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);
```

It should be:

```py
target_user = browser.find_element_by_id("brSecuredUsersLookupInput")
target_user.send_keys(config['sec_group_removal']['target_user']['name_key']);
target_user.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);
```